# Any Spring based web push like notification, where I can get notification updated in the web page without page refresh?

Tags: spring, jquery, notifications

Is there any Spring based framework to send notifications to the web page. I have seen http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse I am also looking into something that can support most of the browsers. Is there any framework or add-on in Spring for this functionality for the server-side code? And any jquery framework to support this for the browser?

TIA.

Comment: i dunno much about on the spring horizon, but websockets support a push notification model. that should help you search.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or any useful pointers?

Comment: websockets are a newer, not yet greatly supported technology. socket.io is a project that attempts to provide nice cross browser support, so you might want to try to stand on their shoulders here. Again, i don't know how spring fits in here, but web browser support is the critical and difficult part, which is what I'm pointing you towards.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the "long polling" method. You basically make an ajax request to the server for data on page load. The server waits until data is available before it responds. On the client and server, you can make the request timeout every 30 seconds or so to avoid having too many threads running on the server. The client just reissues the request after timeout.

[This site](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) provides a good introduction to long polling using jQuery.

Spring doesn't really have any explicit features that support this (e.g. pooling the polling threads) AFAIK, but you may look into the new [async support in Spring MVC 3.2](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own servlet as below, for further information refer [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_server_sent_events.htm). As this works with servlet this might work with spring mvc controllers also.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




public class sse extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("SSE Demo");
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        int i=0;
        while(true)
        {

            i++;
            pw.write("event: server-time\n\n");  //take note of the 2 \n 's, also on the next line.
            pw.write("data: "+ i + "\n\n");
            System.out.println("Data Sent!!!"+i);
            if(i>10)
            break;
        }
        pw.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)  
{
    doPost(request,response);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My way of using it would be with javascript's `setInterval()` method along with jQuery AJAX call to get notifications.
on Document ready, call this (in jsp):
`setInterval(callMe, 30000)`

in JS file:

```
function callMe(){
...

  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ajaxNotifications",
  success: function(count){
  alert( "You have: " + count + "notifications now" );
  //stick it to #element or DIV or .class where ever you want.
  }
  error:function(){
  ...
  }
 });
}
```

and finally in Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajaxNotifications", method = RequestMetho.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getMeCount(HttpServletReuest req, HttpServletRespones resp){
//get the desired values from req
...
//fire a reuest via service layer to the database for getting notifs number
...
//Don't forget to return it as a String, be it error or count.

}
```

I hope this gives some idea to you or helps someone else looking for the answer to this question. :)

Comment: Calling a function every n seconds is not a good idea and may flood the server. I've already tried this for my website and THIS IS NOT A GOOD IDEA...